# ¿Como crear botones dinámicos que se puedan mover en tiempo de ejecución ? Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy intentando hacer un sistema de mesas para un restaurant, pero la cosa se está poniendo difícil.
Lo que quiero hacer es un botón que al hacerle click me cree nuevos botones (en tiempo de ejecución/dinámicos - o nuevas mesas del restaurant) y luego poder mover esos mismos botones (mesas) y posicionarlos dentro del Form Principal.

Mi form principal tiene estas 4 variables:

```
 int posMouseFormX, posMouseFormY, posMouseBotonX, posMouseBotonY, 
 posActBotonX, posActBotonY
```

Tengo este código que me crea el botón al iniciar el form:

```
     private void crearNuevaMesa()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = "btn" + i;
            btn.Height = 40;
            btn.Width = 300;
            btn.BackColor = Color.Red;

            btn.Location = new Point(200, 200);
            btn.Text = "SOY UNA NUEVA MESA";
            btn.Font = new Font("Georgia", 16);

            btn.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(btn_MouseMove);

            Controls.Add(btn);
        }
    }
```

Y luego invoco este otro metodo para setearle las coordenadas:

```
      private void btn_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        posMouseFormX = posActBotonX + e.Location.X;
        posMouseFormY = posActBotonY + e.Location.Y;
        if (botonPresionado == true)
        {
            moverBoton();
        }
    }
```

Pero me rompe en el e.Location.X del metodo btn_MouseMove y no se porque !!!!
Alguien me ayuda ??

Comment: que quiere decir que se rompe? tira algun error?

Comment: claro, tira error en "location"

Comment: Son unos genios! Muchas gracias por su 1) buena onda, 2) su ayuda!
A la tarde voy a probar las soluciones y ver cual me sirvió más ! Ahora estoy trabajando.
Luego les acepto las respuestas!
Otra vez, muchisimas gracias a todos

Comment: para la proxima vez, agrega el error completo por favor. Mira [ask]

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi, lo voy a mirar y tener en cuenta :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gerardo tiene razón, la firma del controlador de evento `MouseMove` espera un `MouseEventArgs` que sí tiene la propiedad `Location`. Pero tienes algún que otro problema mas.

`e.Location` en el evento `MouseMove` del botón te va a devolver la posición del ratón **relativa al botón**. Esto obviamente no va a permitirte moverlo como esperas.

Te dejo una solución sencilla para mover un botón cuando pulses en el y mientras no sueltes el botón del ratón. Primero, añado una variable para almacenar el botón que se ha pulsado en el formulario:

```
private string botonArrastrando="";
```

Después añadimos los eventos necesarios en la creación del botón:

```
private void crearNuevaMesa()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Name = "btn" + i;
        btn.Height = 40;
        btn.Width = 300;
        btn.BackColor = Color.Red;

        btn.Location = new Point(200, 200);
        btn.Text = "SOY UNA NUEVA MESA";
        btn.Font = new Font("Georgia", 16);

        btn.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(btn_MouseMove);
        btn.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(btn_MouseDown);
        btn.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(btn_MouseUp);

        Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

Como ves, añado los eventos `MouseDown` y `MouseUp`. Ahora estos serían los manejadores:

```
private void btn_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point l = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    if (((Button)sender).Name==botonArrastrando)
    {
        ((Button)sender).Location = l;
    }
}

private void btn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    botonArrastrando = ((Button)sender).Name;
}

private void btn_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    botonArrastrando = "";
}
```

Como ves, cuando se pulsa un botón, se guarda su nombre en la variable que controla que botón se está moviendo, y cuando se suelta se borra dicha variable. Luego, en el `MouseMove` se toma la posición del cursor usando [`PointToClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient(v=vs.110).aspx) para obtener dicha posición con respecto al formulario, y si el botón es el que estamos moviendo, ponemos su posición en la localización del cursor.

Answer (score 3):

Muy buenas,

Creo que el problema lo tienes en la implementación del método  **btn_MouseMove**      ya que el parametro **e** lo defines como **EventArgs** y deberías declararlo como **MouseEventArgs**, ya que de otra forma no reconoce la propiedad **Location**.

Te dejo el método corregido:

```
private void btn_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        posMouseFormX = posActBotonX + e.Location.X;
        posMouseFormY = posActBotonY + e.Location.Y;
        if (botonPresionado == true)
        {
            moverBoton();
        }
    }
```

Un saludo y espero que te ayude.